# About mov in assembly

Tags: assembly

move the contents of the register bx into the register ax

```
MOV ax, bx
```

Why is the syntax so strange?

`Mov ax,` (to) `bx` actually means `move` contents of `bx` to `ax` ,is there any historical reason to define it this way?

Comment: As some guys explained below, this is quite odd at the beginning, but it becomes natural. If you prefer you could use some AT&T assembler, like GAS (for Windows or Linux). The code you typed as `mov eax, ebx` would be `mov %ebx, %eax` in AT&T syntax

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider a code

```
x = 5
```

This probably assigns value 5 to x. Would you like 5 = x?

Similarly, You should not try to compare the language English with coding. Thats what historically also happened. English might say move this to that. But computer architects like that to this.

So basically the process of :

```
X := Y
```

could be better summarized as :

```
MOV X, Y
```

Comment: I've always felt that using the equals sign for *assignment* might be confusing for newcomers. In algebra, the expression `x = x - 5` would mean your equation is unsolvable, but it means something completely different in C. :)

Comment: Assignment in paper was traditionally `X ← Y`, and has become either `X := Y` or `X = Y` because ASCII lacks left arrows. APL uses `←`, as you can see on some of the code-golf challenges on this site.

Answer (score 7):

```
MOV ax, bx
```

This means, ax = bx (move bx to ax, more exactly, copy bx to ax). In this Assembly syntax first operand is destination - this is usual case, for example, in C functions:

```
strcpy(dest, source);
```

In AT&T Assembler first operand is source. Generally, it looks strange and AT&T Assembler users make interesting bugs because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language)

Syntax: x86 assembly language has two main syntax branches: Intel syntax, originally used for documentation of the x86 platform, and AT&T syntax. Intel syntax is dominant in the MS-DOS and Windows world. In the Unix/Linux world, both are used because GCC only supported AT&T-syntax in former times.